# Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I tried editing a post which was missing a single symbol in an equation and got the message in the title. Since edits are subject to peer review anyway, is it really necessary to go hunting for ways to change 5 more characters?

Comment: There is also a feature request to remove this limit on math.SE or at least for edits where MathJaX code is changed: [Minimum suggested edit length](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/minimum-suggested-edit-length)